# A* Search Algorithm Inaccuracy

Tags: python, algorithm, search

So I have been getting into coding for a little while now and am currently making an A* search algorithm as a side project. I used the manhattan distance for my heuristic, and calculated the cost by finding the length of the path taken from the source to the node being explored. It seemed to be doing pretty well once I got it working and tried it out a few times, but then I tried the grid in the image below and ran into a problem.

[image]
(Ignore the blacked out 16 and 17 in the optimal path, I did that after it ran)

As you can see, the path that my algorithm took was not optimal, as there was a shorter path available by going to the right. However, I manually calculated f(n) = g(n) + h(n) for all nodes in the algorithm's path as well as the first node in the more optimal path and found that f(n)<sub>algorithm</sub> < f(1)<sub>optimal</sub> always:

[image]
(f(n)<sub>algorithm</sub> goes back up to 92 if you keep going, but no further than that)

So, I am curious if my algorithm is flawed, or if A* is not always optimal. I have heard in multiple places that it is optimal, so I am inclined to believe the former, but I can't wrap my head around how I would get the algorithm to check the optimal path, since it is always supposed to check the node with the lowest f. Any help would be appreciated.

I can also include my code if need be, but I feel like this is a more conceptual question, so I am leaving it out for now.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing diagonal movement makes A* search inadmissible if using manhattan distance heuristic: [Why allowing diagonal movement would make the A* and Manhattan Distance inadmissible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547400/why-allowing-diagonal-movement-would-make-the-a-and-manhattan-distance-inadmiss)

Comment: It's not so much that A* search is not optimal when diagonal movement is allowed. You can use A* perfectly well on those kinds of graphs. It's just that the Manhattan distance heuristic is inadmissible when diagonal movement is allowed. Your heuristic function can't over-estimate the true cost to the goal for A* to be optimal, as doing so might lead you to ignore potentially optimal paths, such that when you reach the goal, the optimal path has not been explored (it might have been ignored because it's true cost was over-estimated). Manhattan distance overestimates the cost of a diagonal move.

Comment: If you want to perform A* on this type of graph, you just have to choose a different heuristic, like Chebyshev distance (maximum coordinate distance rather than summed coordinate distance)

Comment: @inordirection That makes a lot of sense, and I see now that the overestimation was exactly what happened with my example; it was too big so it was never explored. I will edit my answer and take a look at the Chebyshev distance to possibly implement a version of my program with it. Thanks for the help :)